# How can you get Xcode to collapse/fold all properties along with methods?

Tags: xcode, xcode10, code-folding

Xcode has the ability to fold methods & functions as part of its multi-folding capability.  But one of the things that has always annoyed me is it doesn't *also* fold properties, either with observers (willSet, didSet) or with computed values (get, set).

Currently, after folding all methods and functions, I have to go to each property, one-by-one and fold them as well.  This is really time-consuming, let alone very annoying.

My question is if there's any way to tell Xcode to fold all properties, hopefully together with the methods/functions.  I don't care if it's a multi-step thing as long as I don't have to select the properties individually.

Comment: This would make a great enhancement request for Apple!

Comment: Done. Apple bug/suggestion #44768808. In the meantime however, is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am slightly confused on what you are trying to ask - are you asking how you can unfold all functions within a class at once?

Comment: No, I'm asking how can you fold properties along with functions. For instance, if a property has a `didSet` observer, it's wrapped by brackets around the property.  When you collapse all, those bracket sets are not also collapsed and I have to manually collapse them individually. IMHO, if you do 'collapse all', then *anything* (i.e. *all*) things that can be collapsed, should collapse.

Comment: As of Xcode 13.1 this still doesn't work. Bump.